running a python code on raspberry pi 5 to test ultrasonic_sensor
I have updated the code to look like this:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
#GPIO Mode (BOARD / BCM)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
 
#set GPIO Pins
GPIO_TRIGGER = 5
GPIO_ECHO = 6
 
#set GPIO direction (IN / OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)
 
def distance():
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
 
    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
 
    StartTime = time.time()
    StopTime = time.time()
 
    # save StartTime
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        StartTime = time.time()
 
    # save time of arrival
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        StopTime = time.time()
 
    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = StopTime - StartTime
    # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
    # and divide by 2, because there and back
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2
 
    return distance
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        while True:
            dist = distance()
            print ("Measured Distance = %.1f cm" % dist)
            time.sleep(1)
 
        # Reset by pressing CTRL + C
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by User")
        GPIO.cleanup()

I have tried:
sudoing as root
running as root
reinstalling rpi.gpio
the GPIO interface is enabled in the configuration settings.
I always get the same error: RuntimeError: Cannot determine SOC peripheral base address
Note that I also tried:
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo adduser pi gpio

pip and setuptools are up-to-date
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools


Installing from Source: Instead of using pip to install RPi.GPIO,I try installing it directly from the source code. Clone the GitHub repository and install it manually:
git clone https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-gpiozero.git
cd python-gpiozero
sudo python setup.py install

And I still get the same error!

I read that you need to use gpiod for the Pi 5. Details here: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/control-raspberry-pi-5-gpio-with-python-3
Does that help? I don't have a Pi 5 to try it out.

This question may yield more help over at Raspberry PI stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.
